# Buscar último registro de acesso com MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query, distinct

Suponha que eu tenha a tabela `clientes`:

```
--------------------------------------
| ID| Cliente |    Data_Registro     |
|-------------------------------------
| 7 | Joaquim | 2019-07-17 09:45:00  |
|-------------------------------------
| 6 | Timóteo | 2019-07-16 07:42:00  |
|-------------------------------------
| 5 | Timóteo | 2019-07-13 07:42:00  |
|-------------------------------------
| 4 | Joaquim | 2019-07-11 07:42:00  |
|-------------------------------------
| 3 | Gallvão | 2019-07-11 15:42:00  |
|-------------------------------------
| 2 | Gallvão | 2019-07-11 15:41:00  |
|-------------------------------------
| 1 | Gallvão | 2019-06-11 07:00:00  |
--------------------------------------
```

Essa tabela armazena as datas e horas que os clientes acessaram meu sistema, como eu poderia fazer um consulta SQL (Mysql) para conseguir listar os últimos acessos de cada cliente, por exemplo:

```
--------------------------------------
| ID| Cliente |    Data_Registro     |
|-------------------------------------
| 7 | Joaquim | 2019-07-17 09:45:00  |
|-------------------------------------
| 6 | Timóteo | 2019-07-16 07:42:00  |
|-------------------------------------
| 3 | Gallvão | 2019-07-11 15:42:00  |
--------------------------------------
```

Tentei usar o DISTINCT só que a data me atrapalha exibindo mais de um resultado por cliente.

Tentei com a seguinte SQL mas não me retornou a última data.

```
SELECT * FROM clientes GROUP BY Cliente ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula GROUP BY com a função de agregação MAX:

```
SELECT Cliente, MAX(Data_Registro) 
FROM clientes
GROUP BY Cliente
ORDER BY Cliente;
```

Comment: Complementando a resposta do amigo @anonimo, coloquei o ID, Cliente e Data na query:     `SELECT id,
  Cliente,
  max(Data_Registro) AS Data_Registro
FROM SuaTabela 
  GROUP BY Cliente;`

Comment: Estava fazendo a resposta, mas o @anonimo foi mais rapido, então pode testar online a solução, segue [exemplo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRS5QZWR33rkXZmoUrxPE/0)

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou beleza! Esqueci desse MAX()

Comment: Maravilhoso, obrigado! Funcionou.

Comment: @Edvaldo Lucena: apenas deixando claro que apesar desta construção funcionar no MySQL ela não está de acordo com o padrão SQL-92 e não funciona em outros SGBD.

Comment: Oracle funciona, e acredito que atende SQL-92 @aninomo

Comment: Desde que exista uma dependência funcional, o que não é o caso de ID e Cliente acima.

Comment: @anonimo não entendi sua afirmação, mas como você conseguiu ajudar o colega, está ok.

Comment: Veja a documentação: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: anonimo, pode responde minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário

Comment: pode responder a minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/469237/identificar-registros-sequenciais-de-cada-usuário

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer fazer uma consulta dos ultimos clientes que tiveram acesso

Você poderia tentar fazer da seguinte forma

```
select Cliente, Data_Registro from *tabela* where (select max( Data_Registro) from *tabela*) group by Cliente
```

espero ter ajudado.